# multiple htaccess url rewrites with hash (url fragments) stuck in loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a physical file  with a hash tag: `/home/information/index.php#cookies-and-data`

If I browse to it then the page scrolls to the right section no problem.

If I add a rewrite so it rewrites: `/home/information/cookies-and-data` to the above then that also works fine.

However I am trying to mask the physical structure so want `/home/information/cookies-and-data` to rewrite to `/information/index.php#cookies-and-data` (but still actually returning the url at the top)

My attempt so far is

```
RewriteRule ^information/(.*)$ /information/#$1 [NE,R]
RewriteRule ^information/(.*)$ /home/information/#$1 [NE,L]
RewriteRule ^information$ /home/information [L]
```

I'm trying to convey:

```
Transform information/[anything] to information/#[anything]
Transform information/#[anything] to /home/information/#[anything] and return
(or) Transform information to /home/information and return
```

However I get stuck in an infinite loop situation.

I have the (perhaps wrong) assumption that if a rule does not have an L then it will move the the next line keeping any rewrites that have happened.

Also, I am away that clients do not send up # in requests, hence I am trying to keep it all server side till the rewrite is complete.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't rewrite to an URL with an hash, you can only redirect to it.

So, this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^information/(.*)$ /information/#$1 [NE,R]
```

Is redirecting you to the intended URL, but because the server can't see you added the hash, it applies again, as `/information/` (part without the hash) matches `^information/(.*)$`, hence the infinite loop.

You would have to redirect to a different URL to avoid infinite loops.

About the `L` flag, it doesn't mean a matched redirect will wait till the rewrite processor finds it. You may get redirected before you reach the rule with an `L` flag:

> It is possible that as the rewritten request is handled, the .htaccess file or  section may be encountered again, and thus the ruleset may be run again from the start. **Most commonly this will happen if one of the rules causes a redirec**t - either internal or external - causing the request process to start over.

This is from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

which is exactly what happens here. The rest of the rules is not processed because the first one redirects to the same URL over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for this. Clears things up a bit. Might need to go back to the drawing board.

Comment: I would seriously consider using some JS and redirect to `/information/?hash=cookies-and-data` or something similar and then parse the GET parameters in JS to scroll to the correct part instead of trying to redirect to hashes. This is very slippery, as you can see :-)